# How can I print from DeepSee Dashboards?

Tags: pdf, printing, dashboard, intersystems-cache, intersystems

Intersystems DeepSee provides a version of Apache FOP for pdf render. I'm facing "java probably not in path" in csp error page. I've tried to set JAVA_HOME at "../@jdkinstallpath@", "../@jdkinstallpath@/bin" with the same result. Cache 2014.2. Any advices?

Answer (score 3):

bin should not be in your JAVA_HOME definition.  You want the directory above bin.

Comment: Thank you! I just missed reboot after setting variable part.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open-source [DeepSeeWeb](https://github.com/intersystems-ru/DeepSeeWeb) project for DeepSee dashboard rendering. It can print them too.